# Finding the left hand side limit with absolute value

Tags: limits

I have the following limit problem, and I need to find the limit as x approaches 1 from the left hand side, however, I can't get to the correct answer. I always land up with the answer of 2 but the answer should be -2. Can anyone help?

Here is the Question:

```
lim(as x approaches 1 from the left-hand side) (x^2 - 1)/abs(x-1)
```

This is what I have done:

```
lim (x^2 - 1)/abs(x-1) = lim (x-1)(x+1)/(x-1) = lim (x+1) = 1+1 = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed out the "abs" from the denominator in your first step. That's all.